# How to debug my own web service

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, debugging, jboss

We have a web service, it is used from other modules of our company. For some reason, I need to call our web service as a client.

```
WebServicesLocator ws = null;
ws = new WebServicesLocator();
ws.setEndpointAddress("IntegrationServicesPort", serviceUrl);
IntegrationServices service = ws.getIntegrationServicesPort();
SaveResponse saveResponse = service.save(saveDelivery);
```

My question is, I need to debug this save(..) function that I am calling. When I start debugging our client code, it doesn't fall into save(..) method, it skipped that part. It does call save(..) method but I can not debug that method even if I put breakpoints to that method.

We have a desktop application. First I trigger my service from a page then in this service I am remotely calling our web service , which is running on another server, My question is there anyway that I can debug inside this webservice.

I am using eclipse. JBoss 4.2. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Down voters please share your bright ideas or convince me to delete my post.

Comment: I did not down vote this, but I can explain.  The web service call is likely calling into a completely separate application/codebase/container/etc.  In order to debug it, you will need to connect an ide/browser to the remote server with the code that is running on that server.  If you can provide more detail as to where the service is running, we could probably give more assistance.

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to debug a webservice if you cannot connect to the container running that webservice.  This would violate so many security issues.  Consider being able to debug a google webservice from your application simply because you are calling into it.  It likely is doing a number of secure things that simply cannot be debugged from the caller of the webservice.

That being said, it is possible to debug a webservice running in a container that you have access to and if you have access to the source code.  We run many of our services using Tomcat and I can remotely connect to the server and debug the code.  Each container that runs an application varies in how you connect remotely to debug, but are typically well documented.

Comment: I have the source code of webservice of course in my local computer. As I understand, I need to reach the container that my webservice is running in and there are some procedures to connect remotely to container. Thank you